# Unable to update the text using useState

Tags: reactjs

I am converting a class based component to a functional component
But in functional component state is not getting updated.
Could you please update what might be the issue.
I tried putting a alert & its working

I have converted previously working below code-base :

```
class Spice extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: 'Welcome to XYZ '
    };
  }   
  nameChangeFunction() {
    this.setState({
      title: 'Welcome to Authentic XYZ World'
    });
  }
```

And the Calling Snippet:

```
 render() {
const spiceList = [
   ..,
   ..,
   ..
];    
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>

    <button className='tc ma5' onClick={() => this.nameChangeFunction()}>
      Check Out
    </button>
    <br />
  </div>
  );
}
```

New functional component is created as below, but its not updating the title, onClick.

```
    const SpiceHookBased = () => {
      const [title, setTitle] = useState("INITIAL XYZ Title");
      const changeTitle = () => {
            return setTitle("some value changed");
      }

      return {
        render() {
          const spiceList = [
            ..,
            ..,
            ..
          ];

          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{title}</h1>

              <button className='tc ma5' onClick={changeTitle}>

            </button>  
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

In second case, its not updating new text title.
Kindly suggest a correction
Thanks

Comment: the initial state is showing but not the changedTitle is thats your issue

Comment: code looks fine. Do you see any error in console?

Comment: have you tried `.bind()` with this `this.nameChangeFunction().bind()` function ?

Answer (score 2):

In the codesnippet there was multiple return and render. See the below codesnippet and check

Apart from that the code looks fine, you can remove the return and write it in a single line

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("INITIAL XYZ Title");
  const changeTitle = () => setTitle("some value changed")

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>

      <button className="tc ma5" onClick={changeTitle}>
        Click Me to change title
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59565615-so-updating-state-using-usestate-546ye)

Comment: But I am using this component elsewhere in index.js, which does the final job of rendering

Comment: Can you just fork the codesandbox which I have created and add the missing part. So I will check and update on it. Kindly fork and create it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return the `setTitle` function in your update function.

Also there is no need for the `render()` method in functional components, when you return an object like you are doing it just turns the component into a regular `function`, not a react `Component`, so that is likely the reason your `useState` hooks aren't working.

Try changing your functional component to this:

```
const SpiceHookBased = () => {
      const [title, setTitle] = useState("INITIAL XYZ Title");
      const changeTitle = () => {
            setTitle("some value changed");
      }
      return (
            <div>
              <h1>{title}</h1>

              <button className='tc ma5' onClick={changeTitle}>

            </button>  
          );
    }
```

EDIT: I saw on another answer you said you are using this component elsewhere which "does the final job of rendering". That is the problem, you are essentially trying to use this component as a function, which doesn't understand react hooks, and thats why the hooks aren't working.  If you want to use that type of pattern you need to return a new `Component` with any added `props` that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, yes I am using above referred component in index.js elsewhere, wherein I call it like- '      <Switch>
        {/* <Route exact path='/' component={Spice} /> */}
        <Route exact path='/' component={SpiceHookBased} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>'